# OpenMPI breaking out of a loop

Tags: openmpi

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to break out of a loop using OpenMPI in c.

Here's my loop

```
 for( i=1; i<=steps;i++) {

    do_calculation(psi,new_psi,&mydiff,i1,i2,j1,j2);

    if (breakNow == 1) {
       break;
    }

     diff = find_difference();
    if(myid == mpi_master && i % iout == 0){
       printf("%8d %15.5f\n",i,diff);


       if (diff == 0.00) {
        printf("DONE!");

        breakNow = 1;

         MPI_Bcast(&breakNow, 1, MPI_INT, mpi_master, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
       }          
    }
  }
```

I need to break all of the processors out of the loop when there is a difference of 0.00 but it seems like the breakNow variable isn't being broadcast to all the processors. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`MPI_Bcast` is a collective operation. You need to call it in **all** processes in order for it to complete. In the process whose rank matches `mpi_root` the broadcast will behave like a send operation and in all other ranks it will behave as a receive operation.

Just move the call to `MPI_Bcast` outside of the conditional. May be the right place is just before the `if (breakNow == 1) break;` line.

Another suggestion: if `find_difference` returns the same value in all processes, you can do something similar to:

```c
for (i = 1; i <= steps; i++) {

   do_calculation(psi, new_psi, &mydiff, i1, i2, j1, j2);

   diff = find_difference();
   if (i % iout == 0) {
      if (myid == mpi_master) {
          printf("%8d %15.5f\n", i, diff);
          if (diff == 0.00)
             printf("DONE!");
      }
      if (diff == 0.00) break;
   }
}
```

If `find_difference` only gives meaningful results in the master process, then modify as follows:

```c
for (i = 1; i <= steps; i++) {

   do_calculation(psi, new_psi, &mydiff, i1, i2, j1, j2);

   diff = find_difference();
   if (i % iout == 0) {
      if (myid == mpi_master) {
          printf("%8d %15.5f\n", i, diff);
          if (diff == 0.00)
             printf("DONE!");
      }
      MPI_Bcast(&diff, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, mpi_master, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      if (diff == 0.00) break;
   }
}
```

(I have assumed that `diff` is of type `double` and preserved the original semantics of your code to check for zero difference once every `iout` steps)